# In Emacs, how to have "File/Open Recent" menu to ignore currently opened ones?

Tags: emacs, recent-file-list

In Emacs, the "`File`" menu has a "`Open Recent`" entry, which displays the N first elements of  `recentf-list` variable.

I understand the `recentf-list` variable must contain all latest opened files (ordered by most recently opened), but "`File/Open Recent`" unfortunately shows the same files, including files which are currently opened in Emacs: Selecting one [already opened] will simply switch to the corresponding buffer (not related to an "Open Recent" action).

Would it be possible to exclude (in "`File/Open Recent`" only) all files currently opened in Emacs ?

**Example**:

Below is my current buffers list. I did comment the "irrelevant" ones. I have currently 9 opened files.

```lisp
(buffer-list)
(   ;; #<buffer *scratch*>
    ;; #<buffer *Async-native-compile-log*>
    ;; #<buffer *Minibuf-1*>
    ;; #<buffer *temp-0*>
    
 [...]
 
 #<buffer passwd>
 #<buffer c/Makefile>
 #<buffer brchess/Makefile>
    ;; #<buffer *Messages*>
    ;; #<buffer *scratch*>
    ;; #<buffer  *Minibuf-0*>
    ;; #<buffer *Native-compile-Log*>
    
 [...]
 
 #<buffer boot-disk.org>
 #<buffer beaglebone-buster-setup.org>
 #<buffer init.el>
 #<buffer emacs-cheatsheet.org>
 #<buffer 2023/Makefile>
 #<buffer list-pgn-games.php>
    ;; #<buffer *Compile-Log*>
    
 [...])
```

Below is `recentf-list` value (first 9 are currently opened - see above). The "`File/Open Recent`" shows first 10 elements:

```lisp
("/etc/passwd"**
 "/home/br/dev/www/devs/php/chess/list-pgn-games.php"**
 "/home/br/dev/advent-of-code/2023/Makefile"**
 "/home/br/org/emacs-cheatsheet.org"**
 "/home/br/.emacs.d/init.el"**
 "/home/br/org/beaglebone-buster-setup.org"**
 "/home/br/org/boot-disk.org"**
 "/home/br/dev/tools/c/Makefile"**
 "/home/br/dev/brchess/Makefile"**
 
 ;; files above are currently opened in Emacs
 
 "/home/br/list-all-ppa.sh"
 
 ;; "File/Open Recent" (10 entries) shows all above entries, first 9 are useless.

 "/home/br/dev/userspace-rcu/include/urcu/arch/x86.h"
 "/home/br/dev/userspace-rcu/include/urcu/arch/generic.h"
 "/home/br/dev/userspace-rcu/doc/examples/list/cds_list_add_rcu.c"
 "/home/br/dev/userspace-rcu/include/urcu/list.h"
 "/home/br/dev/brchess/include/debug.h"
 "/home/br/dev/tools/config/home/.bashrc.br.lorien"
 "/home/br/dev/tools/config/home/.bashrc.br"
 "/home/br/dev/test/Makefile"
 "/home/br/dev/test/definitions.h"
 "/home/br/dev/test/definitions.c"
 "/home/br/dev/test/main.c"
 "/home/br/.bashrc.br")
```

In this example, I would like "File/Open Recent" to skip the 9 first entries.

Note: I am not really fluent in Elisp, unfortunately.

**EDIT 1**, following first answer received: I believe altering `recentf-list` (with `remove-if`) will not work, as some information would be lost forever: When closing one of the 9 buffers above, it will not "re-appear" in menu (it should), and likely `~/.emacs.d/recentf` file will also lose some information.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize option `recentf-exclude` or `recentf-keep`, or both, adding a predicate that filters however you like (e.g., exclude files currently visited in a buffer). Function `buffer-alist` gives you the list of currently existing buffers. You can filter that using a function such as `cl-delete-if(-not)` or `cl-remove-if(-not)`.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. Where should I put this `delete-if/remove-if` ? I suppose it cannot be used on `recentf-list` itself, as, if I close one of the buffers in example, it should "re-appear" in menu list (and "permanent recentf" information, i.e. `~/.emacs.d/recentf) should contain all files, including those currently opened).

Comment: See the doc for those user options (`C-h v`). You'll need to define a predicate that filters the way you want. You can use `cl-(delete|remove)-if(-not)` in your filter definition.